# Intent calls - avoid calling oneself

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Works fine: The app I am working on is getting called to open text files** (byte arrays) as work data files (pure old text files (.se and .si, not registered MIME file types, my apps input files are never .txt or .csv) and xml-files). And if the content is OK opens a session displaying the file content as list reports. Getting intent calls from the Filer apps or appended to email. (This is the basic business frame of the app).

This is how the intents are received and how I reject by wrong content (works fine when called by any other app but mine):

```
if (action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) {
    // Open data from other app with intent
    String scheme = intent.getScheme();
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String sFileName = null;
    if (scheme.compareTo(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) == 0)
        sFileName = Utils.getContentName(resolver, uri);
    else if (scheme.compareTo(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE) == 0)
        sFileName = uri.toString();
    int iRet = (-1);
    byte[] readData = Utils.ReadInputData(resolver, uri);
    if (readData == null) {
        // Open data by file name
        iRet = ... 
    } else {
        // Open data by byte array (file data from the other app)
        iRet = ... 
        }
    }
    if (iRet == 0) {
        // OK
        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    } else {
        // Failure
        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null);
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

It all works very fine opens incoming correct files. It also works fine if the Android filer, other filer apps or emails try to call for a text file that doesn't have correct content the answer is, rejection, OK.

**Works fine: The app is also calling other apps to display text files**, csv-text (.csv) files (MS Excel etc) and tabbed text (.txt) files (MS Word etc) of the reports shown on the screen (for more analyse and presentation in those apps).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(FilePathName);
String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(FilePathName);
// From Build.VERSION_CODES.N there is entire different file view intent business
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.getApplication(),
            activity.getApplication().getPackageName(), file);
    // We have to ask around for permissions to display the file
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if(resInfoList==null)
        return;
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        // An attempt to exlude oneself (don't work)
        if (!packageName.equals("com.my.app"))
            activity.grantUriPermission(
                    packageName, 
                    uri, 
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION 
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
} else // Elder up to Android 6
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension));
try {
    activity.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    ...
}
```

This works fine when other applications receive the intent-call.

**My problem is: There is an obvious risk my app is calling itself** (user selects my app on a call from my app or my app is the only plain text app responding). And that **wouldn't be a problem if it wasn't so that my app crashes rejecting its own files** (wrong content), but not other apps intent-calls.

**Actually I have two solution paths, and I can't make any of them work?**

1. Filtering away calling myself with the resolveInfo, if (!packageName.equals("com.my.app"))
2. Solving the crash after rejecting my own files on intent-calls

**Filtering away calling myself with the resolveInfo** I don't get my own app in the List resInfoList so I can't skip it??? It is supposed to work, according to other Stackoverflow Q/A, but not for me? But after it, the app is getting called by my own intent (the HAXM emulator has no other csv-interpreting app, so it sends the intent call without an app selection).

**Solving the crash after rejecting my own files**, I have no clue what is causing it.

*Yes, I can have and handle multiple activities of work files, one by the app itself opens a file, different from filers and email apps activities. And it works fine with 2,3 and 4 activities and getting a rejected call, them all survive. I consider the multi activity capability a major app feature. And this problem would still be there with only single activity capability.*

**Yes I might destroy my own activity by this.finish()** when I call myself. And then I would need to (something like) send the activity ID with the intent and if it is the same just drop it. But  but the amazing thing is, **it crashes also without calling this.finish()** at the rejection? In fact if I do nothing getting intent calls from myself, it also crashes after leaving, but not by intent-calls from others. Makes me confused, so that idea, also does not work.

**Any good hints on a solution path or explanation why I fail?**

Here is my crash:

```
2019-02-21 05:39:27.482 6149-6149/com.me.myapp.Myapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-02-21 05:39:27.484 6149-6149/com.me.myapp.Myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.me.myapp.Myapp, PID: 6149
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 5, found: 0 Pager id: com.me.myapp.Myapp:id/pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.me.myapp.MainActivity$ViewPagerAdapter
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1135)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:451)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

And when I make intent calls from the Android filer (no other app is responding on a CSV-file, and I reject it as above) I get the following message in the dump (but my app do not crash, but I guess it is my calling app activity that crashes):

```
2019-02-21 05:57:15.811 7746-7746/com.me.myapp.Myapp E/ActivityThread: Activity com.me.myapp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.me.myapp.MainActivity$5@e1fa714 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.me.myapp.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.me.myapp.MainActivity$5@e1fa714 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Comment: Can you post the crash?

Comment: You mean if I have log?

Comment: Yes the crash log/stacktrace.

Comment: Added excepts from my Logcat list from a emulator session (all before looks to be OK). It is talking about unregisterReceiver()?? What is crashing is obviously my apps intent calling activity #0 rather than the receiving activity #1?  Like as if it (#0) would be gone after dropping #1. It is very good if we find out why it crashes. But also how to filter myself away so I don't call myself would be good having working? Either would make the situation work, both correct would be the best.

Comment: Look at your viewpager `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 5, found: 0 Pager id: com.me.myapp.Myapp:id/pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.me.myapp.MainActivity$ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: Well the onCreate was creating a new Activity and I did not get any onResume (because the receiver (0 tabs) was the same activity as the the caller (5 tabs)). Well this is because I expect every onCreate to be a new Activity and every onResume to be restoring of an old activity. Intent-calling myself is in fact the same activity both the caller and the receiver, but I expect it to be a new Activity getting it into onCreate.

Comment: The basic problem is to detect my app calling itself. I looked and looked to find a Activity ID number or something that could be stored (in my JNI) so I can check if it is the same activity as a previous activity (and just return the JNI activity ID), This is not possible in the Java code because all Java data is wiped getting a onCreate but possible with the JNI. So the question is how do I identify myself (my Activity to check if it is the same), or marking the intent with a specific flag (me), any suggestion what is proper would be nice. I think more to find a solution?

Comment: Still unsolved: I tried some things to restore data, but I must as a receiver distinguish between myself and others as callers (activities, intent tokenflags or something). And it will do. But I would also like to have a ability to filter at the resolveInfo  stage.

Comment: I solved my problem by improving my MIME handling so my app impossibly will be intent-called from itself. However my questions are still very interesting to know, for the future. How do I detect I make an intent call to myself? How do I filter away myself with the resolveInfo process?